# Dynamic instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I want my code to be extensible, in a way where at runtime I create the objects.

For example, let's say I have a Grocery class which has an array of fruits and I want to fill this array of fruits with objects which derives from fruits.

```
class Fruit{

};

class Grocery{

    std::vector<Fruit*> m_fruits;
};

class Apple: Fruit{

};

class Pineapple: Fruit{

};
```

Now at runtime I want my Grocery class vector `m_fruits` to be filled with class objects of Apple and Pineapple. So is it possible in some way.

if I add another fruit as strawberry in future, its object will be created and added to the vector of Grocery dynamically without changing the implementation of Grocery class?

Code help will be appreciated.

Comment: use pointers, or you will get sliced fruits... (google "C++ slicing")

Comment: @smerlin:  can I downvote your comment for bad punning?  =]  ...or at least prune it from the site?

Comment: @smerlin +1 internets for you.

Comment: No it is not homework, I need this in my project at work. I explained it in a scenario easy to understand.

Comment: Oh dear... you got hired as a C++ programmer without understanding C++ polymorphism? I feel sorry either for you or your company, depending on how that came to pass.

Comment: "... will be created and added to the vector of Grocery dynamically without changing the implementation of Grocery class".  Well, considering it has no public methods, and the list is private, no, you can't add anything to it without changing the implementation.

Comment: @smerlin +1 for the comment :-D

Answer (score 4):

Check your textbook.  It probably mentions that you can only treat *pointers* to types polymorphically.  In other words, a vector of *pointers* to fruit can take *pointers* to apples or pineapples.

Comment: UM, there's also references (even though they don't apply in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to make it so your Grocery class can generate any type of fruit. Even fruit that has been implemented after the grocery class has been locked away, I suppose you might be after something like the following?

```
typedef Fruit*(*FruitInstantiatorPtr)();

template<class T>
Fruit* FruitInstantiator()
{
   return new T();
}


// Then in Grocery have a function like:

static void AddFruitGenerator(FruitInstantiatorPtr instantiatorFunc, string fruitTypeName);

////
//Then someone somewhere can go:

class MyNewFruit:Fruit{};

MyGrocery.AddFruitGenerator(FruitInstantiator<MyNewFruit>, "myAwesomeNewFruit");
```

And that way your `Grocery` class will be able to instantiate any type of fruit added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assum that `Fruit` has pure virtual functions (denoted by `virtual func() = 0`) you would need to store pointers to Fruit objects inside your vector `std::vector<Fruit*>`.

Unfortunately standard containers aren't particulary good at handling pointers and you will have to delete all objects inside your vector in the destructor of your `Grocery`. You might consider `shared_ptr` from TR1 or the boost library.

A word on naming: `Instantiation` isn't the proper word in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store objects of a derived type by value in any container of a base type without object slicing occuring.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Use a vector of raw pointers to the base type, e.g. `std::vector<Fruit*>` and manage the lifetime of the individual `Fruit` instances yourself (this is the least desirable option).
2. Use a vector of smart pointers to the base type, e.g. `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Fruit> >`, and allow reference counting to manage the individual items' lifetimes.
3. Use `boost::ptr_vector<Fruit>` to store the items, and the items' lifetime are bound to that of the containing `ptr_vector`.

Depending on your need, #2 & #3 are preferable. #1 should be avoided, as it involves manual effort to manage the lifetimes and could easily result in memory leaks if done incorrectly.